# Getting "no module name 'setup tools' " despite setuptools being up to date

Tags: python, windows, setuptools

As a bit of background, I have some experience with python 2.7 in the past, but none before now with python 3.x or installing modules, since most of the stuff I did in the past was fairly mundane.

I am trying to install discord.py to make a discord bot, but in trying to pip install it, I am getting Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1, with a "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'setuptools' ". However, I installed setuptools successfully (as far as I know, I can import it and such), and can't figure out what the problem is).

If I'm leaving anything important out that you need to answer my question, please let me know. As I said, I'm new to installing modules/packages.

Comment: sounds like you have it installed for python2 but not python3

Comment: I thought that I made sure that this wasn't the case (it was my first thought as well). I used "py -3 -m pip install -U setuptools" but it said that it was up to date.

Comment: The `pip` command you're running is probably for an outdated Python 2.7 installation that lacks setuptools. Run `where pip` to find where it's located.

Comment: It looks like this may have been the problem. I reinstalled python 3.6 and it seems to have worked now (although I tried this before, so I'm still not entirely sure of what the issue was).